# Show my close vote

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close

Going through my old close votes, I noticed the following:

1. If I have cast an `off-topic` close vote, I cannot see what that vote was, as I cannot navigate to the `off-topic` section as I would be able to navigate before I cast my vote:

[image: off topic vote]

2. If other people voted to close the question, but for different reasons, then I cannot tell which vote is mine:

[image: multiple votes]

Can the modal for this feature be updated so that I can see which specific vote I cast?

Comment: Not saying this is a bad idea, but I'm curious as to why you want to know this?

Comment: @Becuzz One of the reasons is that I periodically walk through my votes tab to see if my vote is still valid. Unfortunately my memory doesn't serve me well on this topic, especially as I casted more than 1k close votes :)

Comment: @Cristik Yes, that's pretty annoying sometimes.

Comment: Revisiting and reassessing your Close Votes is useful, because a question may have been improved in the mean time. (Yes! It does actually happen!) Removing an then-obsolete Close Vote is, IMO, important because I have observed a Monkey See Monkey Do effect where 1 or 2 votes can trigger the rest *even if a post gets improved*. But you need to remember why you voted in the first place.

Comment: Well, does the question still deserve closing? If so, don't obsess over having chosen the best possible reason, by than it likely won't be closed anyway.

Comment: @Deduplicator it's not necessarily a matter of obsessing, but also a matter of learning. If the other 3 votes are different than mine, perhaps I miss-evaluated the question. I'd like to know this, so I can catalogue the next questions I review the proper way.

Comment: And even if it would be about obsessing, there's nothing wrong about obsessing to do things the right way :)

Comment: Well, without obsessive people SO would have *somewhat* more crap around. Keep up the great work;)

Comment: Additionally, could we have (opt-in?) notifications for (non-minor?) edits (by OP?) on questions I have downvoted/close voted?

Comment: I'd like this just out of curiosity. It's annoying that generally you can see the breakdown of how other people are voting but this occasionally becomes blocked.

Comment: @AwalGarg - Post that as a separate feature-request on Meta. How would it be determined what is "non-minor"? Why does it matter if the edit was made by the OP or not?

Comment: @AwalGarg: I don't know of any way to get notifications, but I did write [a script to look through voted posts that have changed](//stackapps.com/questions/6755/get-a-list-of-posts-youve-voted-on-that-have-been-edited) that might be of value.

Comment: @NathanTuggy you could poll the post's [timeline](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/316287/timeline), with some localStorage and fancy logic, it should be pretty easy to figure out.

Comment: @TinyGiant: Polling *n* posts individually sounds like my idea of a bad day. That means (among other things) that notification frequency changes with the number of total votes, to avoid throttling.

Comment: And let's not forget http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/54917/155739 while we're at it.

Comment: I agree with that

Comment: a 'post-edited-after-voting' search might be nice too.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare "non-minor" by the standard 6 char edit limit already existing on the network. And by OP because a lot of times, we downvote/closevote questions because it is roughly unclear what the question is asking about. Such details generally aren't (shouldn't be?) added by the community, but the OP themselves.

Comment: Hi Cristik, did you find a way to see what you close-voted for?

Comment: @TT. unfortunately not, waiting for a feature like this to be implemented :)

Comment: Same here. I hope my extra upvote results in extra attention.

Comment: I wouldn't remove a close vote that became unwarranted if the question still warranted being closed for a separate reason.

Comment: Not sure if I can say BUMP, but I'll say BUMP because I want that feature.