# Almost link-only flag declined

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, not-an-answer

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28716397/how-to-design-accordion-tableview-using-swift/28875546#28875546) as NAA and the flag got declined. IMO, this is a link-only answer, as there are no technical details in the answer that will help the asker.

Similarly, I voted to close the question (I can't exactly recall the closing reason as I [cannot see it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316287/show-my-close-vote)). Did I wrongly evaluate the question and the answer? Are this kind of questions and answers acceptable for Stack Overflow?

Note, I'm just trying to figure this out for future flags, not necessarily complaining about the declined flag :).

**Edit** At the time I posted the question the answer had a score of 14 and was the accepted answer (it might still be). This means that at least 14 people (including the asked) found it useful, and considering this should the answer still be flagged, even if it's a link-only one?

Comment: I think that's link-only, yes.  "How do I do X?"  "I did X, go look at it over here."  Contrast the [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35849752/3614835) that explains which functions to call from which other functions, and links to a GitHub repo at the end of the answer.  (And the auto review comment actually got a response!  That's how it _should_ work, not that it usually does...)

Comment: On the other hand, I don't think a mod will ever delete an 11-score answer in response to an NAA or VLQ flag, and the community can't do it in review.  You're left with waiting until the link breaks and using a custom flag if you want it gone, or commenting in the hope the answerer will edit it.

Comment: That question should have been closed, asking for a tutorial is off-topic.  But it wasn't, such an answer is an inevitable result.  Aim your ire, you can still VTC the question.

Comment: @HansPassant I also voted to close it, however looks like the flags vanished (probably due to an edit?).

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom I hope mods aren't looking only at the number of votes an answer has :)

Comment: Of course the flags vanished, the moderator isn't going to delete a "nice answer" for you and will not judge posts on technical merit.  Don't ask somebody else to do something that you should do yourself.

Comment: @HansPassant I didn't expect the mods to delete the answer, I flagged it as  the answer deserved being flagged, or at least this is what I thought at that moment, and now I'm trying to figure out if it was the best decision or not.

Comment: @HansPassant "Don't ask somebody else to do something that you should do yourself" - I'm afraid I don't get this

Comment: In response to comments here: I don't think the question is asking for a tutorial. I get the impression that the OP looked for a tutorial, didn't find one, and asked here how to do it instead. Possibly too broad, but not much wrong with the question otherwise.

Comment: [Why are accepted answers immune from Flagging link-only answers as Not an Answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135920/288751)

Comment: `I didn't expect the mods to delete the answer, I flagged it as the answer deserved being flagged` is a non sequitor. When you flag something, you're asking a moderator to delete it. In cases such as this, a moderator can a) decline the flag, b) delete the content, or c) convert the content to a comment. If you can edit the relevant content at the end of the link into the answer in blockquote format with proper attribution, do so (and don't flag), otherwise, use a custom flag explaining why you found it impossible to edit, and why you think it is causing harm.

Comment: Thanks a lot @TinyGiant for the meta link, that questions was very useful. Can I mark mine as a duplicate of that? :)

Comment: Nah, it's a m.SE question, this is an m.SO question. We cannot currently mark questions on different sites as duplicates of each other.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Oh hey, I declined that. It's a borderline answer, but [I'm pretty strict about these things](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer):

> Yes, they're both very short, and yes, they contain links. But strip the markup, and you still get at least a little bit of useful information. Does that mean these answers should forever hang around the site? No, not necessarily - if it turns out they're just not that useful, they should probably still be removed - or at very least, down-voted so that they rank below other answers.
>
> Just remember: if the text of the post contains an honest attempt at answering the question, then it is an answer - so don't flag it otherwise, and if you do, don't complain if your flag gets declined.

I'm drawing a fine line here between an answer that depends on an off-site resource and an answer that *literally doesn't exist* until you follow a link. I think it's an important line. Especially when...

> Similarly, I voted to close the question

You voted to close it as "unclear", which it kinda is. The question was eventually closed as "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic", which it also is. Such questions *usually* attract answers like these, because they're *kinda asking for them*:

> Don't get me wrong, it's still a bad answer - but when the question is kinda asking for bad answers this is to be expected. Close or flag the question and move on - this is much more efficient than hanging around to babysit it by deleting every crap answer that inevitably shows up.

Note that *originally*, all of the other answers to that question were just as bad (or worse!) than the one you flagged; getting rid of the question (and preventing further answers) is the most expedient way to put a stop to such trouble. I say "originally" because ONE answerer responded to a review auto-comment by [editing his answer to add detailed information](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35849752/revisions). In light of this, it may actually be worthwhile to edit the question to fit this answer, and then remove the answer you originally flagged.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications, I see now that flagging is not the best option for this kind of answers.

Comment: Could you please explain where is that bit of usable information in  stripped answer? I fail to see it: "Try this, <stripped> I've implemented accordion menu using swift language for ios. the code is converted from objective C tutorial "<name of another offsite resource>" to swift .

Comment: The asker is asking for a Swift version of code in a different question, @Oleg. The answer provided it. If the question had asked the same thing as the other question (but "in swift") this would've been a non-answer; but it didn't. And no one edited it. Thus, they're all gone now. So it goes...

Answer (score 4):

As per me the flag should be declined. As @Shog9 said, this is borderline, and might get any result.

I say that this flag is invalid, because **it answers the question**. You should raise an **NAA** flag only when the answer **does not** attempt to answer the question in **any** way. This was answering the question, but in a very poor way.

If you see such an answer, you actually have a few options:

- Edit the answer by including the content required from the page. This would make the answer correct, and thus would help future visitors.
- Downvote the answer, post a comment, and after about a day, if the user doesn't change the answer, you might flag it as **VLQ** or just edit.

I would actually go with a mix of both the points. The answer is bad, but provides some information. So I would just:

- I would've posted a comment, notifying the user to change the answer. If it doesn't change, I would've just edited it and downvoted.

I won't flag it, as mostly flagging would lead to deletion of answer, and that means loss of content. But that content is useful and might be useful to a future visitor. Also, why do you want to waste a moderator's time on something you can solve yourself? Just edit it.

I would've also downvoted because, the answer was poor, and votes are used to decide the quality of the answer (Not flags).

Comment: This is what I was thinking also after reading the SE question posted by Hans. Best course of actions would have been: comment and ask for more details, downvote, get back later on and see if answer got improved (and remove the comment if it did). If the OP doesn't improve its answer other people will see my comment and possibly downvote it also.

Comment: ^^ I agree. Just one more thing. If the user does not edit the answer, it would be better editing the answer. of course downvoting is going to be done in either case, whether the user edits the post or not, but editing the answer might save time for future viewers. EDIT: Also, if the user is not editing, why do you want to depend on the user. Do your job, edit the answer. If the user keeps roll backing the edit, custom flagging is the best.

Comment: I was referring to the OP editing, and other users downvote it. Adding technical details on my own is not always possible, especially as the linked library belongs to the OP and not sure how correct would my techs be.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I think I misunderstood you. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score -10):

Please, don't kill the questions and answers on the basis of "just google it". Any (sic!) question from Stack Overflow can be googled and has answer on some 10th page. Relevant questions plus valid and concise answers make Stack Overflow a topnotch resource. Veterans, your answers are not "just for this lazy newbie". You also answer the Legion that will google the question later.

Sure, you can make Stack Overflow a "premium" club, but you are risking to lose your TA. Please, play nice and answer relevant questions.

Comment: How is this an answer to the question (ironic as the question's about NAA flags)?

Comment: @Jon. Cristik writes "I wanted to eradicate an answer, because it links a different resource" (that is my take on their comment). Well, abusing NPOV, NAA, etc is easy, but not wise. If you see some "check out this link" response you don't have to delete it or flag it as NAA or prosecute the responder. If you are this proactive - check the link and rewrite the answer in a clear and concise way.

Comment: @StepanLenevich The response to someone posting a non-answer is not to write your own answer and edit it into their post.  If you want to write your own answer, write your own answer and post it under your own name.  But whether or not you want to write your own answer to the question has no bearing on how you should moderate someone else's answer.  In this case, it's low quality, but not "Not An Answer".  If it was just a link, it *would* be Not An Answer, and would merit deletion.  If you really think that the information in the link is that valuable, post your own *quality* answer.

Comment: @Servy   I _don't_ suggest to keep irrelevant answers. But if someone's reply answers a question, don't just kill it with "answer doesn't follow the letter of law".  This is counterproductive. If you are this proactive - rewrite it to follow the guidelines. In this case - make a summary of the solution, proposed elsewhere.

Comment: A question that can be answered by simply giving a link to an external resource is not worthy for SO. If the asker would've google a little bit more he would have found the two github repositories linked by the two answers to the question. Questions like this don't add value to the site as the seeker is just asked to redirect his query to another site, by clicking the provided link.

Comment: @StepanLenevich Like I said, you shouldn't be deleting someone else's answer, writing a new answer from scratch, and editing it into their answer.  You should be posting your own answer instead.  SE has determined that link only answers simply isn't content that we want here.  They just don't add value to the site, and we don't consider them appropriate.  If you want to write your own answer before flagging such posts, that's your decision.