# What did other people vote to close with?

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close

If you have already voted to close a question, you can only see the vote breakdown for the top level of close reasons.

But I picked one of the detailed off topic reasons and I was unable to see if other votes agreed with me or not.

It wouldn't be difficult to implement. Could I please have a way to see what people are voting for after I have cast my own vote?

[Show my close vote](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316287/show-my-close-vote) is *close*, but not the same. I want to see what everyone ELSE voted for in off-topic because I remember what vote I cast. It's possible that solving one would solve the other, of course, but not necessarily.

Comment: If this doesn't get implemented - I'm sure there's a userscript for it, as the information is contained within the html. I had a script grabbing that information, along the lines of `.close-question-link[data-isclosed='false'] .existing-flag-count` - though I'm not sure if it's still valid

Comment: `"It wouldn't be difficult to implement."` How do you know?

Comment: @KevinWorkman It's just a link; the behavior is already present in the UI before you cast a vote.