# Cannot see "off-topic because..." sub-topics tally after I casted vote

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

After voting for "off-topic because..." I can no longer see the vote tally of the sub-topics.

Is this intentional?

[image]

Comment: @bro Want to explain what the OP is missing? If you mean that they voted... Well, they already know that, they pointed that out in the comment. If you mean it is telling them what off-topic reason they voted as... Well, I'm not seeing it either? So it'd be really helpful if you clarified. (As an answer if the latter.)

Comment: @bro If you are suggesting to retract the close vote then I would be delighted to be the first to bestow the wisdom on to you that a confirmation box appears stating "Are you sure (you cannot vote again after retracting)?"

Comment: @psubsee2003 Part 1 of that question seems relevant to me but that question seems to just be stuck in limbo unfortunately. It hasn't even been closed as `status-by-design` so does this mean it's being considered?

Comment: If you've already voted to close for any reason you can't click into any of the reasons. I assume it's just because after you've voted you get the retract popup instead of the vote popup. I've often wished I could see the sub-topics too, though.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus we don't have a lot of visibility into what SE is doing.  I've upvoted both here any in the duplicate as I think it is a very useful feature, but given they cover the same ground, it seems unnecessary to split the discussion up and it would be best to keep it in one spot.  If you want to get extra attention on the old post, you can leave an "answer" there about why this would be a good feature to have

Comment: @Don'tPanic Not sure if I am missing something but the retract pop-up only shows up if you click the blue retract button; you can click "Close" as many times as you please after casting your vote.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Thanks, I guess it's [worth a shot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366098/2191572)

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm using the wrong terminology. I mean when you click "close" on the question after you've voted to close, the dialog that opens is for retracting your close vote, so it doesn't have the same functionality as the close dialog because that isn't necessary for retracting your vote.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Oh ok, now I see what you meant. Thanks

Comment: This MSE feature request is pretty similar too: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101571/seeing-close-vote-details-if-ive-already-voted

Comment: @Don'tPanic kinda, sorta, but not at all. I don't care who voted for what, I just want to see a tally of the sub-topics. Part 1 of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/316287/2191572 is closest to what I want.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I have a personal, as yet unpublished, userscript which allows you to click-through to the other panes in the close-vote dialog once you've close-voted. I'll put it on the list of things I need to break into their own script, so I can release it.